# VB.net Get Number of datagridview rows that are selected

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to get the number of rows in the datagridview that have been selected, so that i can make sure that only one row has been selected by the user, but i cant find a solution anywhere.
help,please!!

Comment: `DataGridView1.MultiSelect = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the DataGridView.

> Gets the collection of rows selected by the user.

However if your purpose is to enforce single select, then @LarsTech's comment to set `MultiSelect = false` is better.